Disable specific optimizations in Clang
I am trying to disable specific optimizations during the Clang compilation process through the command line. However, I couldn't find a systematic way to disable individual optimizations comprehensively—just a few flags for specific cases.
My primary goal is to avoid instruction reshuffling and branch merging, specifically when similar branches in an if clause are optimized into a single branch, starting from an optimization profile of minimum -O2.
Is there a way to selectively disable specific optimization passes in Clang (maybe using -mllvm or other options)?

For gcc, you can do: -fno-something. For a complete list, look at man gcc (or info gcc) and look in the Optimization Options section. There is a flag for each individual optimization. (e.g.) -faggressive-loop-optimizations so we can use -fno-aggressive-loop-optimizations. Add these -fno-* options after (e.g.) -O3 on the command line. clang supports a number of gcc -fwhatever command line switches (but not all). See: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html

What is the actual goal you want to archive? Do you want to make debugging easier?

@tl-photography.at When I do the llvm-objdump -S of the compiled object I get the C lines as a comment before the geneated assembler code for that line. However, when I employ -01 and upwards optimizations, for certain programs (usually when there are if clauses with similar branches), the C lines on top of the assembler code are completly off. So I needed to find the oprimization that yield this issue and remove it. If I use -O0 or the #pragma clang optimization off directive this issue disappears. Ultimately yes, I need to make debugging easier.

Even with -O2 debugging should be good. If you output debug symbols with -g. You debugger should be able to cope with this. -Og or similar should not really be necessary.
